# display parent and all child side-by-side using SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table

```
 INPUT Table:

 Col1 | Col2 
 -----------
   A  |  B
   B  |  C
   C  |  D
   F  |  G
   G  |  H
   I  |  J
   K  | Null
```

Can we write a SQL query to print an output like this

```
OUTPUT Table:

Parent | C1 | C2 | C3
----------------------
   A   |  B | C  | D 
   F   |  G | H  | Null
   I   |  J | Null Null
   K   | Null Null Null
```

The approach I would take is using self joins on Table2.Co2 = Table1.Col1
However, I am struggling to append columns side-by-side and the logic on getting the number of columns needed dynamically

And also as a followup question, if we are given the output table, can we write a query to get the input table

can be any sql - oracle , mysql etc

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The answer depends on (at least) two clarifications. First, do you have an upper bound on the number of "generations"? In your example there are no more than four generations from the earliest ancestor to the latest descendant. If you don't have an *a priori* upper bound, you will probably need to use dynamic SQL - not a best practice. And second, in your example each parent has at most one child. Will that always be the case? If not, it's not even clear what your output table should look like.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample data has a simple linear relationship, three deep.  You can handle this with `left join`s:

```
select t1.col1 as parent, t2.col2 as c1, t3.col2 as c2, t4.col2 as c3
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.col1 = t1.col2 left join
     t t3
     on t3.col1 = t2.col2 left join
     t t4
     on t4.col1 = t3.col2
where not exists (select 1 from t tp where tp.col2 = t1.col1);
```